# SqlAlchemy: No Foreign Key error, although the foreign key is defined

Tags: python, sqlalchemy

I developed a Framework based on SQLAlchemy.
The code to import a table in my mapper is the following:

```
        for table in tables:
        columns = []
        relationships = {}
        for column in inspect.getmembers(table,
                                         lambda a: not (inspect.isroutine(a)) and (
                                                 type(a) == Column or type(a) == RelationshipProperty)):
            if type(column[1]) == Column:
                column[1].name = column[0]
                columns.append(column[1])
            else:
                column[1].argument = list(filter(lambda t: t.__name__ == column[1].argument, tables))[0]
                relationships[column[0]] = column[1]
        sql_table = Table(table.__tablename__,
                          base.metadata,
                          *columns,
                          extend_existing=True)
        mapper(table, sql_table, properties=relationships)
    base.metadata.create_all()
```

Then I defined various tables:
Permission.py:

```
class Permission(TableModel):
__tablename__ = 'permission'

network_id = Column(String(255), ForeignKey("network.id", ondelete="CASCADE"), primary_key=True,
                    default=check_network_validity)
user_id = Column(Integer, ForeignKey("user.id", ondelete="CASCADE"), primary_key=True)
user = relationship("User", back_populates="permissions",
                    foreign_keys=user_id)
network = relationship("Network", back_populates="permissions",
                       foreign_keys=network_id)
type = Column(Enum(TypeEnum), primary_key=True)
validated_by = Column(Integer, ForeignKey("user.id", ondelete="CASCADE"), nullable=True, default=None)
end_validity = Column(DateTime, nullable=True)
created = Column(DateTime, default=datetime.utcnow())
last_updated = Column(DateTime, default=datetime.utcnow(), onupdate=datetime.utcnow())
```

and Network.py:

```
class Network(TableModel):
__tablename__ = 'network'
id = Column(String(255), primary_key=True)
customer = Column(String(255))
url = Column(String(50))
rollout_api_key = Column(String(20))
rollout_password = Column(String(20))
is_sandbox = Column(Boolean, default=False)
is_new_stack = Column(Boolean)
date_deleted_ = Column(Date, nullable=True)

csm = Column(Integer, ForeignKey("user.id", ondelete="CASCADE"), nullable=True)
sol = Column(Integer, ForeignKey("user.id", ondelete="CASCADE"), nullable=True)
# host = Column(String(50), ForeignKey("keycloack.name"), nullable=True)
permissions = relationship("Permission", back_populates="network",
                           cascade="all, delete-orphan", single_parent=True)
requested_logs = relationship("RequestedLog", back_populates="network",
                              cascade="all, delete-orphan",
                              single_parent=True)
```

When I start the system, no problem: Tables are created with the right columns, and the right foreign keys. But as soon as I try to write in one table (Anyone, even another one than Permission or Network), I have this issue:

> File "D:\Github\sol-rollout-management-service\venv\lib\site-packages\sqlalchemy\orm\interfaces.py", line 197, in init
> self.do_init()
> File "D:\Github\sol-rollout-management-service\venv\lib\site-packages\sqlalchemy\orm\relationships.py", line 2077, in do_init
> self._setup_join_conditions()
> File "D:\Github\sol-rollout-management-service\venv\lib\site-packages\sqlalchemy\orm\relationships.py", line 2141, in _setup_join_conditions
> self._join_condition = jc = JoinCondition(
> File "D:\Github\sol-rollout-management-service\venv\lib\site-packages\sqlalchemy\orm\relationships.py", line 2524, in **init**
> self.*determine_joins()
>
> File "D:\Github\sol-rollout-management-service\venv\lib\site-packages\sqlalchemy\orm\relationships.py", line 2657, in *determine_joins
> util.raise*(
>
> File "D:\Github\sol-rollout-management-service\venv\lib\site-packages\sqlalchemy\util\compat.py", line 178, in raise*
> raise exception
> sqlalchemy.exc.NoForeignKeysError: Could not determine join condition between parent/child tables on relationship Permission.network - there are no foreign keys linking these tables.  Ensure that referencing columns are associated with a ForeignKey or ForeignKeyConstraint, or specify a 'primaryjoin' expression.

To add about it: The program worked without problems 2 weeks ago. In the meanwhile, I checked that Python updated from version 1.3.19. I tried to force back to 1.3.18, but it didn't change anything

Any idea? even top test something?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The issue was actually that the same module was loaded with different paths. So my foreign key didn't refer to the correct table.